# awkward array ak.unzip behaviour

Tags: uproot, awkward-array

When I acess a root file and extract the data I want like in following example:

```
events=uproot.open(filename)["btagana/ttree;6"]    
jet_data=events.arrays(filter_name=["Jet_nFirstTrack","Jet_nLastTrack","Jet_pt","Jet_phi","Jet_eta"],library="ak")
```

Where the sorting of the keys of this array doesn't resemble the sorting of the list used to filter the keys.If I now use ak.unzip():

```
jet_data=ak.unzip(jet_data)
```

is the sorting reliable and reproducable? If I open different root files, would I be able to achieve the same "sorting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a question about Uproot. In this line:

```py
>>> jet_data=events.arrays(filter_name=["Jet_nFirstTrack","Jet_nLastTrack","Jet_pt","Jet_phi","Jet_eta"],library="ak")
```

the `filter_name` is just a filter, accepting or rejecting branches from the ROOT file. Those branches have a natural order in the file, and the output is probably that order (and therefore stable upon repeated attempts, unless a dict is involved at some point and you're using Python <= 3.5).

If you want to enforce an order, pass your list of branch names as `expressions`, rather than `filter_name`. That argument has different meaning: `expressions` can be simple formulas; `filter_name` can have wildcards—therefore, a character like `*` has very different meanings in each!

Alternatively, you can reorder the fields after reading the array by slicing with a list of strings. There's no performance penalty for doing so—it's just rearranging metadata (time to completion does not scale with the length of the array). [This documentation](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.Array.html#nested-projection) has some examples (including more complex cases where you're selecting fields within fields, but the simple case is enough for your issue).

**Edit:** I should add that fields of records in Awkward Arrays have a reproducible order. They're not unstable hashmaps like dicts in Python <= 3.5. They're actually two equal length lists: the ordered fields (which is what `ak.unzip` returns) and ordered fields names (which `ak.fields` returns). The names are optional—without field names, records become tuples.